# Issue with ForEach-Object in the pipeline

Tags: powershell, foreach-object

Bonjour

This a question from a newbie... Could you tell me why this works?

```
$Data = Import-Csv -Path ./Data1.csv -Delimiter ';' 
$Data | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Question = $_.Question -replace "`n", "<br/>"
  $_.Response = $_.Response -replace "`n", "<br/>"
}
$Data | Export-Csv -Path "./Data1-bis.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

And why this doesn't?

```
Import-Csv -Path ./Data1.csv -Delimiter ';' | 
ForEach-Object {
  $_.Question = $_.Question -replace "`n", "<br/>"
  $_.Response = $_.Response -replace "`n", "<br/>"
} |
Export-Csv -Path "./Data1-bis.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

I've been locked on this for a while now, so your help is welcome
Regards, Philippe

Comment: In your second eample, ```ForEach-Object``` isn't returning anything out for the next command in the pipeline to consume, so it's effectively ```$null | Export-Csv ...```. If you add a third line inside the body to return the current object out to the pipeline it *should* work - just add this: ```$_``` as the last line insode the ```foreach-object```

Comment: Yes that's a common idiom.

Answer (score 3):

The second example doesn't work because [assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.3) don't produce output thus `Export-Csv` is not receiving any input. For it to work properly you would need to output the updated object (`$_`):

```
Import-Csv -Path ./Data1.csv -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
  # update here
  $_.Question = $_.Question -replace "`n", "<br/>"
  $_.Response = $_.Response -replace "`n", "<br/>"
  # output here
  $_
} | Export-Csv -Path "./Data1-bis.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```